# How can I export a single trigger from mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers, export

I need to re-create a single trigger in another mysql database - is there an easy way to export a single trigger?

Comment: if you can just cut and paste, `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger` should do.

Answer (score 8):

What you want is a dump of single trigger of your db.

You can take inspiration from [this](http://www.ducea.com/2007/07/25/dumping-mysql-stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers/) article and from [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

For example, this command export only the stored procedures and triggers:

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt <database> > outputfile.sql
```

However, I do not think you can dump a single trigger. Since it's only one, maybe it's easier to recreate another dabatase.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want the syntax of the original CREATE TRIGGER statement, [SHOW CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-create-trigger.html) should help you out.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this query to get a trigger definition directly out of MySQL:

```
SELECT  ACTION_STATEMENT
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
WHERE   TRIGGER_SCHEMA = 'mydbname'
AND     TRIGGER_NAME = 'mytable_BEFORE_INSERT';
```